# CSS to duplicate one row table

Tags: html, css

[image: 1 row table]

I need to convert the above from a 1 row table into CSS so it can adjust size without issues if a phone is being used. I tried a number of things with CSS but no luck.

Notice the text is centered vertically and horizontally, there is space all around the text, there is no spacing between the table cells, so no white space in between each cell. Also the entire row should be centered horizontally.

How can I make it look like this on the desktop and also look nice on a mobile phone? Should I still use a table and if so how can I keep it looking good on a mobile phone?

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Is this an actual HTML table? Can we see some HTML so we know what we are working with? How do you want it to display on phones? Have you tried media queries? What do you mean by "duplicate one row table"? You can't really duplicate anything with CSS.

Comment: Only problem with flexbox is IE only supports it fully in the current version and not at all in anything less than IE 10

Comment: Gary, I think you are right a flexbox would work, but I found the example complicated and felt like I was struggling again to make it look right. I ended up going with a div display inline block and the CSS below and it worked.

Comment: Jon P, that was the other issue I noticed with a flexbox, seems the code has changed and a lot of examples out there are out of date, not to mention the IE support issue you brought up, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For vertical aligning, you can use "line-height" value. This also determines approximately how height the box will be.

For horizontal aligning, you can use "text-align: center".

I guess you already know "background-color" to set the colour of background.

Also, you can use "padding-left" and "padding-right" to put some space around.

If you use "div" blocks as "display: inline-block", and then do not put any new line between them, there won't be any space between them. Like below:

```html
<div class="box1">16 Active</div><div class="box2">1 In Escrow"</div>
```

Comment: This worked, although I am not sure what you mean "do not put any new line between them", so I still have some spacing, however, I noticed on a phone it turns into 3 rows and the spacing actually looks better than without, so I am going to keep the spacing. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here is a proper solution.  View the jsfiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/2r6j9y8d/

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="box is-blue">16 Active</div>
    <div class="box is-green">1 in Escrow</div>
    <div class="box is-gray">7 Expired</div>
    <div class="box is-yellow">26 Sold</div>
    <div class="box is-gray">6 Withdrawn</div>
    <div class="box is-pale">56 Total</div>
</div>

.box {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    line-height: 36px;
    padding: 0 12px;
}

.is-blue {
    background-color: lightskyblue;
}

.is-green {
    background-color: palegreen;
}

.is-yellow {
    background-color: lemonchiffon;
}

.is-gray {
    background-color: #ddd;
}

.is-pale {
    background-color: #f8f8f8;
}

@media (min-width: 480px) {

    .box {
        width: 50%;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {

    .box {
        width: auto;
    }
}
```